# Nuxt - render simple html page(dynamic) without layout and styles

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to render a simple HTML page in Nuxt,

I tried
layouts/empty.vue

```
<template>
  <nuxt />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {},
};
</script>
```

and page
pages/simple.vue

```
<template>
<div>Redirecting to <a :href="dynamicUrl">{{dynamicUrl}}</a>.</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  layout: "empty",
  asyncData() {
   // ... code to get dynamicUrl for the user
  }
}
</script>
```

It works, but the page is loaded with styles, javascript other nuxt-related things.
What I need is - just a simple HTML page(like a static page) but with dynamic content(without any styles and javascript files).
How to do it in nuxt?
This is what I need in the output:

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=\'.....dynamicUrl'" />
    <title>Redirecting...</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div>Redirecting to <a :href="dynamicUrl">{{dynamicUrl}}</a>.</div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: You can use `layout: false` if you want to get rid of the layout. As of the style, I'm not sure what do you have by default but you could also reset those. Browsers do have default styles tho, keep that in mind.

Comment: There is no `app.html` as it could exist before in Nuxt2. Here is the related issue: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/5565 And althought, you may get a nuxt wrapper at some point, I'm not sure about the styling/JS you're talking about.